# python how can I debug this ImportError No module

Tags: python

I am having a problem importing from a specific module, but not importing from modules in general. My project structure:

```
project-folder
  aaa-folder
    __init__.py
    a.py
  bbb-folder
    __init__.py
    b.py
  ccc-folder
    __init__.py
    c.py
```

All the **init**.py files are blank. The project-folder is in my sys.path.

module b:

```
from aaa.a import a_method
from ccc.c import c_method

def b_method(): print 'bye'
print 'hi'
```

module c:

```
from aaa.a import a_method
from bbb.b import b_method

def c_method(): print 'bye'
print 'hi'
```

module a:

```
from bbb.b import b_method
from ccc.c import c_method

def a_method(): print 'bye'
print 'hi'
```

I can import every method from the python shell. Module b and c both run from the command line and simply return 'hi'. When I run module a, I get ImportError: No module named b

Where might I find clues to my problem?

Comment: make sure you set your python path to include the root folder.

Comment: This is using circular imports

Comment: You have circular references (A needs B and C which both need A first). It’s a sign for bad design.

Comment: The circularity as a sign of bad design, I get, and will restructure the lay out of the modules in a more organized manner. None for the module methods have any dependences on other methods in other modules. Even with this independence, would I trigger a circularity error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned a few times in the comments, you are designing you project to use circular imports:

> Circular imports are fine where both modules use the “import ”
>   form of import. They fail when the 2nd module wants to grab a name out
>   of the first (“from module import name”) and the import is at the top
>   level. That’s because names in the 1st are not yet available, because
>   the first module is busy importing the 2nd.

If you place a print statement at the very top of each of those modules, you will see what is happening...

Example a,b,c:  `print "inside aaa" # bbb, ccc`

When you execute module `a`, you will get this:

```
$ python aaa/a.py 
inside aaa
inside bbb
inside aaa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaa/a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bbb.b import b_method
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/project/bbb/b.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aaa.a import a_method
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/project/aaa/a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bbb.b import b_method
ImportError: cannot import name b_method
```

`a.py` goes to import `b.py`, but `b` needs `a`, so it goes back to that module, where it sees the rest of the `bbb` import. Well `b` was only partial loaded at this point, so `b_method` is not yet defined. So you get a crash.

What you should do is avoid having your modules import each other in circles. There should be a set of common modules for which others all import the shared functionality. But as stated in the python faq, it can be worked around by only importing the module namespace (`import bbb`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I pulled the method in question out of the module I wrote it in and put it in a module which contains common methods. I asked my question so I could understand the details of what caused the ImportError and your answer was perfect for that!